# Nokogiri - selecting non-hidden inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have code that selects input elements:

```
html = html.at_css("input")
```

How would I need to modify the selector to exclude hidden inputs from the selection (`type="hidden"`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
html.at_xpath("//input[not (@type='hidden')]")
```

Just tested this with a simple example and it seems to work.